# Transfer value from angularjs to php

Tags: php, mysql, angularjs, linux, bash

I have a site and a form have a form what use this to get data from a mysql: {{product.name}}

now I want to run a script bash using shell_exec, but I dont know how get the value on php variable from the angulaJS  to php:

```
<?php
$macnamex = "{{product.name}}";
$output = shell_exec("./cm-reset2.sh -r 172.31.31.10 -k hk15#inhpAMX -m $namex");
echo "<pre>$namex</pre>";
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

I am trying but the $namex no get the string from angularjs value.

Answer (score 1):

First, how are you sending the form? POST? or GET?, second, what name are you giving the field you are sending?, anyhow, here are both cases:

POST:

```
$macnamex = $_POST['productName']; //Assuming you are sending it as "productName"
```

GET:

```
$macnamex = $_GET['productName']; //Assuming you are sending it as "productName"
```

Comment: Just want to add that you could use `$macnamex = $_REQUEST['productName'];` and it will get both POST and GET variables, if your not sure how the data will be sent. But if you know how it's going to be sent, it's best to use `$_POST` or `$_GET`.

Comment: this file php dont have POST or GET method,  :(

Comment: this is my code, where I want to add the php [document-pluker](http://plnkr.co/edit/zxj3EGWwGYG1HqCS4qtV?p=catalogue)